# Displaying multiple images using their URLs to listview with JSON

Tags: android, json, image, url, listview

I have been trying to load my image urls onto a listview that is the first have to be downloaded can someone please help me.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
 map.put("id", String.valueOf(i));
 map.put("name", "House name:" + json_data.getString("name"));
map.put("address", "Adress: " + json_data.getString("address"));

URL newurl = new URL(json_data.getString("imageUrl"));
 itmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(result).getContent());
 ImageView imagy = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
 imagy.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
  map.put("img",bitmap);//error is here says convert bitmap to type string
  mylist.add(map);
```

Comment: The error kinda says what your problem is: you're trying to put a `Bitmap` object into a `HashMap<String, String>` object.

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing exactly with this code?

```
 URL newurl = new URL(json_data.getString("imageUrl"));
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(result).getContent());
            ImageView imagy = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
              imagy.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
             map.put("img",bitmap);//error is here says convert bitmap to type string

            mylist.add(map);
```

Because you are doing findViewById() and setting image bitmap every time. And then you are adding in mylist.

**Suggestion:**
Instead i would suggest you to add only URL string into HashMap:

```
String strImageURL = json_data.getString("imageUrl");
map.put("img",strImageURL );/
```

And while defining Custom adapter for your ListView, just do as you are doing above inside the **getView()** method of your custom adapter (which you can define by extending **BaseAdapter**).

**Suggestion 2:**
If you want to implement Lazy loading of images inside ListView, then check Fedor's answer given here: [Android - How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3068012/379693)

Comment: The problem is Fedor's only dealing with static images and mine are dynamic.His mstrings(the static list) when i replace with my imageUrl[i] (my fetch from json)doesn't work and associating each detail with the image also i'm having a problem with.

Comment: he he he....instead you can also pass your Array to the custom adapter. You just need to look at the example and ImageLoader class usage.

Answer (score 1):

I hope, ur actual HashMasp is 
HashMap map = new HashMap ();

if so, u can only add String values.
try the following,

```
class House {
    int id;
    String houseName;
    String houseAddress;
    Bitmap image;
}

List<House> houseList = new ArrayList<House> ();

House houseObj = new House();

houseObj.id = i;
houseObj.houseName = "House name:" + json_data.getString("name");
houseObj.address = "Adress: " + json_data.getString("address");

URL newurl = new URL(json_data.getString("imageUrl"));
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(result).getContent());
ImageView imagy = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
imagy.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 

houseObj.image = bitmap;

houseList.add(houseObj);
```

use this list in ur listview adapter.

Comment: hey thanks alot mannn!!! You saved my day...If possible I would have given +10, sorry I can only give +1 :-)